# Equality involving Gamma function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gamma-function

Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n>0$.

Let $$v_n=\int\limits_{\substack{x_1,\ldots,x_n\geq0\\x_1+\cdots+x_n\leq1}}x_{1}^{\alpha_1 -1}\cdots x_{n}^{\alpha_n-1}dx_1\cdots dx_n.$$

i. Express $v_n$ in function of $v_{n-1}$ and show that $v_n=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\cdots \Gamma(\alpha_n)}{\Gamma(1+\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)}$.

ii. Let $a>0$. Compute
$$u_{n}(a)=\int\limits_{\substack{x_1,\ldots,x_n\geq0\\x_1+\cdots+x_n\leq a}}x_{1}^{\alpha_1 -1}\cdots x_{n}^{\alpha_n-1}dx_1\cdots dx_n.$$

The hint I have is to use the previous exercise, where I proved that $\mathrm{B}(x,y)= \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ where $\mathrm{B}$ is the beta function. But I have no idea how to start. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is the domain of your integral $\{x_1+\dots +x_n \leq 1\}\cap \mathbb{R}^n$ or is it $\{x_1+\dots +x_n \leq 1\}\cap(0,\infty)^n$? If you consider when $n= \alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=3$ you would get $$\int_{x+y+z\leq 1}xyz\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{1-x-y}x^2y^2z^2\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$ which diverges to $+\infty$

Comment: @MatthewPilling we are considering the points in $(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_i>0, \forall i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \leq 1$

Comment: You should write that in your post. Otherwise your integral diverges.

Comment: @MatthewPilling  I did, after ii. I do the clarification and in the integral i. I mention the condition $ \leq 1 $

Comment: I understand, but this condition really needs to be stated in the expression of your integral. For example, you wouldn't write $\int_{-\infty}^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and follow up with a footnote indicating that $x$ is positive.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Done, I already corrected it

Comment: "Express $v_n$ as a function of $v_{n-1}$" - Think induction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$0 \le x_1+x_2+ \cdots+ +x_n < a \quad \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le \frac{x_1}{a}+ \cdots +\frac{x_n}{a} <1$.

So change accordingly the integration variables ..

So, for the first, we have
$$
I(a_{\,1} , \cdots ,a_{\,n} ) = \int\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {0 \le x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,n} }  \cr 
   {\left( {0 \le } \right)x_{\,1}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,n}  \le 1}  \cr 
 } } \right.} {x_{\,1} ^{a_{\,1}  - 1}  \cdots x_{\,n} ^{a_{\,n}  - 1} dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,n} } 
$$

For $n=1$ it is
$$
I(a_{\,1} ) = \int\limits_{0 \le x_{\,1}  \le 1} {x_{\,1} ^{a_{\,1}  - 1} dx_{\,1} }
  = {1 \over {a_{\,1} }}\quad 
$$

We can then start a recursion by noting that for a general $2 \le n$ we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & I(a_{\,1} , \cdots ,a_{\,n} ) =
 \int\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{   {0 \le x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,n} }  \cr 
   {\left( {0 \le } \right)x_{\,1}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,n}  \le 1}  \cr  } } \right.}
 {x_{\,1} ^{a_{\,1}  - 1}  \cdots x_{\,n} ^{a_{\,n}  - 1} dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{{0 \le x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,n} }  \cr 
   {\left( {0 \le } \right)x_{\,1}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,n - 1}  \le 1 - x_{\,n}  = u}  \cr 
   {0 \le u \le 1}  \cr  } } \right.}
 {x_{\,1} ^{a_{\,1}  - 1}  \cdots x_{\,n - 1} ^{a_{\,n - 1}  - 1} x_{\,n} ^{a_{\,n}  - 1} dx_{\,1}
  \cdots dx_{\,n - 1} dx_{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{u = 0}^1 {u^{a_{\,1}  +  \cdots  + a_{\,n - 1}  - \left( {n - 1} \right) + \left( {n - 1} \right)}
 \left( {1 - u} \right)^{a_{\,n}  - 1} du}
 \int\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{ {0 \le x_{\,1} /u, \cdots ,x_{\,n} /u}  \cr 
   {\left( {0 \le } \right){{x_{\,1} } \over u} +  \cdots  + {{x_{\,n - 1} } \over u}\, \le \,1}  \cr } } \right.}
 {\left( {{{x_{\,1} } \over u}} \right)^{a_{\,1}  - 1}  \cdots \left( {{{x_{\,n - 1} } \over u}}
 \right)^{a_{\,n - 1}  - 1} d\left( {{{x_{\,1} } \over u}} \right) \cdots d\left( {{{x_{\,n - 1} } \over u}} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = B\left( {a_{\,1}  +  \cdots  + a_{\,n - 1}  + 1,\;a_{\,n} } \right)
 I\left( {a_{\,1} , \cdots ,a_{\,n - 1} } \right) \cr} 
$$
Therefrom  we get
$$
\eqalign{
  & I\left( {a_{\,1} } \right) = {1 \over {a_{\,1} }}
 = {{\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1} } \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1}  + \;1} \right)}}  \cr 
  & I\left( {a_{\,1} ,a_{\,2} } \right)
 = {{\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1}  + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {\;a_{\,2} } \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1}  + \;a_{\,2}  + 1} \right)}}
{{\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1} } \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1}  + \;1} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1} } \right)\Gamma \left( {\;a_{\,2} } \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1}  + \;a_{\,2}  + 1} \right)}}
 = {{\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1} } \right)\Gamma \left( {\;a_{\,2} } \right)}
 \over {\left( {a_{\,1}  + \;a_{\,2} } \right)\Gamma \left( {a_{\,1}  + \;a_{\,2} } \right)}}  \cr 
  & \quad  \vdots  \cr} 
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I also have problems proving i.  Could you give me some hint for the part i.?

Comment: @RicardoCalderón: I put the first steps to solve the first question, can you finish for both questions